# C# В чём отличие автосвойств от полей?

Tags: c#, ооп

В C# для объекта можно объявить автоматически реализуемое свойство, а можно поле(глобальную переменную). Насколько я знаю, оба из них просто хранят значение, которое им задаёт код, не делая с ним никаких операций. Есть ли у них какое-то различие, то есть, можно ли использовать автосвойство там, где поле не подойдёт или наоборот?

Comment: Например если вам нужно внутри объекта читать и писать, а снаружи только читать `{ get; private set; }`. С полем такой фокус не прокатит.